# "TypeError:Networkerror when attempting to fetch resource" when my remote client tries to communicate with my remote server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, https, digital-ocean

I have uploaded a React client to [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) with an SSL certificate to enable HTTPS. I also have uploaded my Express server to Amazon's [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services). The reason for the different host providers is that I wasn't able to upload my client to AWS so I made the switch to DigitalOcean.

The server works great and I get normal responses from it when I use the client from my machine. However, the exact same code doesn't work in DigitalOcean's Nginx server. I get:

```
TypeError:Networkerror when attempting to fetch resource
```

But no response error code. The [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL)/fetch requests aren't visible on the server so they either aren't being sent correctly or they cannot be accepted correctly by the server.

I played around with "proxy" in client's package.json and HOST/PORT/HTTPS attributes as seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) but I realized these have no effect in production.

I have no idea how to fix this. My only guess is that client uses HTTPS while server doesn't, but I haven't found info on if that's a problem.

This is my client's [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) server configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your client lives on a domain different from your API server then you need to make sure you have CORS headers enabled on the API server, otherwise the browser will refuse to load the contents.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more information regarding CORS headers.

Comment: Hi Oliver, my server already has CORS enabled. As I said, there are no problems when I use the client on my local machine to speak with the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You turn off the credentials when running the client on DigitalOcean. Maybe storing a cookie on your client is/ was not possible.